# Directory contents in a list

Tags: python, linux, unix, command-line, io-redirection

I'm trying to figure out how to write a script in python where I list the contents of the current directory with "ls" and then put the result of ls into a list so that I can do something with each one of the elements in ls. I'm actually first trying to do it in my terminal and then I'll script it using python but I can't even get it working in my terminal.

Oh, and I've tried redirecting the output from ls into a file but I don't seem to have permissions to do so:

```
>>> subprocess.call(["ls ", directory_expanded, " > ", "namesoutput.txt"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 478, in call
    p = Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 642, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1234, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Answer (score 3):

How about [`os.listdir`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir)?

```
In [25]: os.listdir('.')
Out[25]: ['blah']
```

Comment: This is the most promising approach. +1

Answer (score 0):

subprocess.check_output should work for anything that's not provided in the standard library. For listing directories just use `os.listdir`.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output